# how to install ros

Tags: ros, installation, apt, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys.

i'm beginner about PC.
so i have problem about installation of ros.
i don't know how to configure my ubuntu repositories.

i use ubuntu 14.10

sorry for my poor question but this is serious problem for me.

please help for solving this problem.

---

Edit: Ubuntu repository configuration done as javier points out!
Thanks a lot!

But, sorry i have one more question.
I try to install  from turtrial 1.2 and now 1.3 done.
now i install the turtrial 1.4 ,sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full, but this sentences ,the package is not found, is displayed.
this error is related to ubuntu setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225543/how-to-install-ros/) by [yoneyama1027](https://answers.ros.org/users/25796/yoneyama1027/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-02-01**:
As the Installation tutorial points out, there is a link with more information about this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

**Comment by [yoneyama1027](https://answers.ros.org/users/25796/yoneyama1027/) on 2016-02-03**:
OK! it works!
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the repository configuration has no need to change in the default settings, so you can start from tutorial 1.2 "Setting your sources.list".
If you have problems like, the package is not found, you should configure it as Javier points out.

---

Originally posted by [kenkiki](https://answers.ros.org/users/25828/kenkiki/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0